# How to wait for page load in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3, firefox-57+

I am using selenium-server-3.7.1 and Firefox 57

How to wait for page to load completely

I tried following
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                            "return document.readyState").equals("complete");

but it is not working

Basically the above command is not recognizing below operations
   [testng] 1535139249496   addons.productaddons    INFO    sending request to: https://aus5.mozilla.org/update/3/GMP/57.0.4/20180103231032/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/en-US/release/Linux%204.1.12-112.14.10.el7uek.x86_64%20(GTK%203.22.10%2Clibpulse%2010.0.0)/default/default/update.xml
   [testng] 1535139249669   addons.productaddons    INFO    Completed downloading document
   [testng] 1535139249818   addons.productaddons    INFO    downloadXHR File download. status=200
   [testng] 1535139249821   addons.productaddons    INFO    Downloaded file will be saved to /tmp/tmpaddon-c61a84
   [testng] 1535139738375   addons.manager  INFO    Skipping background update check
   [testng] 1535139978387   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
   [testng] 1535139978387   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
   [testng] 1535139978409   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
   [testng] 1535139978412   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

I gave hard sleep of 30 seconds to finish these operations
Is there a way to wait for these operations to be completed?

Answer (score 1):

In Automation script, There needs to wait on multiple instance. There can not be use Thread.Sleep(); every time. Page need to wait for JQuery, JavaScript, Angular loading. And which can not be handle by only `document.readyState` We have to wait for all substances if application is built on. So, We can create single method to wait for Page load and that method can call multiple times.

This is the Blog link for same, Which will help you to understand it. [Click Here](https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/)

You can include those method, on which your application is build.

If in case Blog link might loss, there is sample Github project is available for same. [Click Here](https://github.com/swtestacademy/JSWaiter)

Answer (score 0):

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
.withTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.SECONDS) .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Please describe it so that questioner understand it